# JavaScript if conditional expression with 3 parameters?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

this my very first question on stackoverflow, so please forgive me if I am not getting all the etiquette yet.

I am trying to work with a previous script written in JavaScript.  There is an if conditional expression in the code that I do not understand.  The reason it is confusing to me is because it has 3 arguments.  I have never seen an if conditional expression like this in any language, or even in the JavaScript "if" tutorial on http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp.  The code snippet I am working with looks like this

```
if (this.css(alldivs[i], "contentdiv", "check")){ //check for DIVs with class "contentdiv"
    setting.contentdivs.push(alldivs[i])
    alldivs[i].style.display="none"}
```

My question is: What does if(foo, bar, "check") mean?  Is this an old deprecated string comparison function in JavaScript? Why are there 3 variables in the if conditional expression instead of 2?

What are the advantages of the previous code, compared to something like:

```
if (this.css(alldivs[i] === "contentdiv")
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The `if` iself is checking for the return value of the function `this.css()`. The function that has 3 arguments, but the if doesn't.

Comment: Those are not _three_ values, it is _one_ method call …

Comment: That's not an if with 3 parameters. It's a if with ONE parameter that happens to be a function call with three parameters. Look at the brackets.

Answer (score 2):

> What does `if(foo, bar, "check")`

When you have a conditional with comma separated expressions, only the last one matters (the previous ones are also executed, though).

Then, the code is equivalent to:

```
foo;
bar;
if("check") { /*...*/ }
```

But you have this:

```
if (this.css(alldivs[i], "contentdiv", "check"))
```

That means:

1. Run `this.css(alldivs[i], "contentdiv", "check")`, where `this` is an object which has a the method `css` (a method is a function which is a property of an object).
2. Check the returned value.

Maybe you will understand it better this way:

```
var temp = this.css(alldivs[i], "contentdiv", "check");
if(temp) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Except, your initial explanation is not what is happening in the OP's code.  Not sure why you're confusing things by explaining something that isn't even part of the OP's code.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yeah but OP asks that, so I answer both.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down what's happening here.  In this line:

```
if (this.css(alldivs[i], "contentdiv", "check"))
```

You have two things going on.

1. You have a function call `this.css(alldivs[i], "contentdiv", "check")`.
2. You have an `if()` that checks the return value from that previous function call

---

This would be equivalent to this expanded code:

```
var returnVal = this.css(alldivs[i], "contentdiv", "check");
if (returnVal) {
    setting.contentdivs.push(alldivs[i]);
    alldivs[i].style.display="none";
}
```

Comment: Ah yes I see my mistake, thank you.
Yet, this raises another question for me.
What does a css() method do with 3 parameters?
According to <http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2>, when css() is used to get, as opposed to set a css value, it only takes one argument, either a property or an array of properties.  So why in this case is it taking 3 arguments?  Thank you for your help on this.

Comment: @LeonardShelby - jQuery's `.css()` method does not take 3 arguments.  You didn't show the context for us to know what `this` or `.css()` was.  If you can show a larger context of code, we might be able to comment on that aspect of things.  I just assumed `.css()` was a different `.css()` than the jQuery one.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
if (this.css(alldivs[i], "contentdiv", "check")) {
```

Would be equivalent to this:

```
var temp = this.css(alldivs[i], "contentdiv", "check");
if (temp) {
```

So you see, it's not an if taking three parameters. It's an if with one parameter which happens to be a function call that takes three arguments.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know what answer is going to help you, as your question is about code that doesn't appear in your sample.  In this case:

```
if (this.css(alldivs[i], "contentdiv", "check"))
```

The condition is based on the return value of the call to `this.css`.  In the sample you seem interested in:

```
if(foo, bar, "check")
```

The answer is that it's *always* going to evaluate as True because of the way the [Comma Operator](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/) behaves in JavaScript.